# Convert posted value to decimal with number_format

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

I have a number as `10,000` in my post data, and I want to store in db as `10000.00`

I currently have the following: (in Kohana)

```
number_format(input::post('amount'),2,'.','');
```

but this gives me the error:

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Since `$_POST['amount']` = 10,000

Any suggestions how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is causing the problem, you could strip it out using [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

```
number_format(str_replace(',', '', input::post('amount')), 2, '.', '');
```